# Writing a simple integer to Roman numeral program in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do a basic exercise from the book *Learn To Program* by Chris Pine. However, I've bumped into syntax errors where the compiler won't let me use 'end' to close many of my while loops. How can I make this program correct? Thanks.

```
class StdClass

    def roman __romannumber
            __finalnumber = [mthousand,dfive,chundred,lfifty,xten,vfive,ione]

            while __romannumber != 0

                    while __romannumber >= 1000
                        __romannumber - 1000
                        mthousand++
                    end

                    while __romannumber >= 500
                        __romannumber - 500
                        dfive++
                    end

                    while __romannumber >= 100
                        __romannumber - 100
                        chundred++
                    end

                    while __romannumber >= 50
                        __romannumber - 50
                        lfifty++
                    end

                    while __romannumber >= 10
                        __romannumber - 10
                        xten++
                    end

                    while __romannumber >= 5
                        __romannumber - 5
                        vfive++
                    end

                    while __romannumber >= 1
                        __romannumber - 1
                        ione++
                    end
            end
            return __finalnumber[]
    end

    def initialize
        puts = 'Enter you number'
        aby = gets.chomp.to_i
        roman aby
        puts M*__finalnumber[0] + D*__finalnumber[1] + C*__finalnumber[2] + L*__finalnumber[3] + X*__finalnumber[4] + V*__finalnumber[5] + I*__finalnumber[6]
    end

end
x = StdClass.new
```

I'm not sure if the last puts is correct either.

Comment: What is the exact error you are receiving? On a side note, the Ruby community uses 2 spaces for indentation. We also do not prefix our variables with `__` for any reason. You also do not need to explicitly use the `return` keyword. Ruby will automatically return the last thing that was evaluated.

Comment: https://github.com/majioa/rdoba/blob/master/lib/rdoba/roman.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `++` operator in Ruby. You need to write `mthousand += 1`.

`M`, `D`... are constants, and if you haven't defined them, will generate an error. You probably mean `"M"`, `"D"`... instead.

These are the syntax errors you are struggling with; there are also several stylistic issues as Justin Wood notes in comments, that would make this very unRubyish, even if it were correct.

EDIT: There are also logic errors. `__romannumber - 1000` evaluates to a thousand less than `__romannumber`, but does not change `__romannumber`. Numbers in Ruby are immutable, so doing `mthousand += 1` does not change the contents of `__finalnumber`, it only changes the contents of the `mthousand` variable (substituting a new number for the old). `__finalnumber = [mthousand, ....]` will generate an error because `mthousand` is not defined at that point. The correct way to do this would be to first initialise your variables to 0:

```
mthousand = dfive = ... = ione = 0
```

then do your battery of whiles (which, by the way, can be replaced by a judicious use of division `/` and a modulo operator `%`), and only then finally construct an array to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It can be made correct by reading the Ruby manual. `mthousand++` is not an allowed token. A hint for future reference: In order to do correct programming, there is a basic method called "read the manual".

Answer (score 0):

You are making this harder than it has to be.

Rather than using a while loop for each value, such as V and I, try this:

So,

```
if __romannumber > 1000
  mthousand = (__romannumber / 1000).to_i
  __romannumber = __romannumber - mthousand * 1000
end
```

I haven't tested this so it may not compile, but the basic idea is to find the number of times that value is in the number, and then remove it.

As is mentioned, the `to_i` may not be needed, but I included it just in case.

Comment: `to_int(x / y)` in Ruby is written as `(x / y).to_i`; however, if both `x` and `y` are integral, the result is already integral, so there is no need for casting.